# Data types for variables in UNIX

Tags: environment-variables, variable

I have just begun reading UNIX and came across variable definitions. As per the site, I'm referring to UNIX variables being defined directly with the syntax `variable_name=value`.

Do we not have data types associated with the variables?

Answer (score 4):

According to the POSIX standard, environment variables are just plain strings with no associated data types.

However, as an extension, some shells like `bash`, `ksh`, `ksh93`, `zsh` and others allow their variables be typed, like being numeric, an array. Read-only variables or pre-formatted ones might also be supported.

They are commonly typed with either the `typeset` or `declare` builtins.

Here is an example of integer tests with `ksh93` :

```
$ typeset -i var
$ var=abc
$ echo $var # non numerical -> set to zero
0
$ var=0xffff # hexadecimal
$ echo $var
65535
$ var=0xffffffff
$ echo $var
-1           # ksh93 integers are 32 bit signed
$ var=2147483649
$ echo $var
-2147483647  # overflow
```

With the help of discipline functions, `ksh93` variables might be given arbitrary custom types.

Answer (score 1):

In shell scripting, there is only one data type. Everything is text. Different commands may variously interpret the text to suit their needs:

```
$ [ "1" -eq "01" ] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [ "1" = "01" ] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

The first test interprets `1` and `01` as numbers (the second probably as an octal number). The second test treats them as strings.

Comment: You are correct if you stick to POSIX but most shells like at least bash, ksh93 and zsh allow variable typing as an extension.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, yes. +1 for that.

Comment: In `bash` it's not treated as octal: `[ 8 -eq 08 ] && echo yes || echo no` → `yes`